# Find right CGBitmapInfo for a picture

Tags: ios, swift, bitmap, cgimage, steganography

I'm trying to do a steganography app, and since now I've managed to get pixels bytes from actual image and modify them. But I have't managed to rebuild image in a proper way (I get bytes from image, rebuild image, get bytes again and they are not the same). After some debugging I've get to a conclusion. I'm not build image the right way. Since all other vars are pretty standard(see the code below), the only var that I'm not sure what it does and I think is wrong how I use it is bitMapInfo. Can someone help me out to figure what do I need?

```
let bitsPerComponent = 8
    let bytesPerPixel = 4
    let bytesPerRow = Int(image.size.width) * bytesPerPixel
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    var bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Big.rawValue
    bitmapInfo |= CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue & CGBitmapInfo.AlphaInfoMask.rawValue

let imageContext = CGBitmapContextCreateWithData(imageData,
    Int(image.size.width),
    Int(image.size.height),
    bitsPerComponent,
    bytesPerRow,
    colorSpace,
    bitmapInfo,
    nil,
    nil)
let cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(imageContext)
let newImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage!)
```

Comment: When you modify the image, do you save it to a file and then reload it for extraction? If yes, do you save it as a jpeg?

Comment: Yes, I am saving it as a JPEG

Comment: You can't use jpeg when you modify the pixels because its lossy compression modifies the pixels.

Comment: SO MANY THANKS. You got me to the right way. After I've read some more I find out why it does not work. Many thanks, again.